# Are stable manifold for gradient flows embedded submanifold?

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry, manifolds, dynamical-systems

Generally, the stable manifolds $W^s(p)$ of a diffeomorphism $\phi:M\to M$ is no embedded submanifold. The injective immersion
$$ E^s:T_p^sM\to M $$
does not need to be a homeomorphism onto its image $W^s(p)$.

This is a popular image that illustrates this fact:

[image]

However, in the case that the diffeomorphism $\phi$ comes from a gradient flow, I think the stable manifold must be a submanifold. (More generally I think this is the case when there exists a strict Lyapunov function).

Can anybody tell me how to prove this?

Comment: It is true. For a precise reference, see, e.g., Corollary 7.4.1 in [Jost, Riemannian geometry and geometric analysis].